# “sans” and the definite article

Tags: grammaire, prépositions, articles

Usually “*sans*” is placed before a noun without the definite article (*sans doute* or *sans alcool*). But occasionally I see *sans* with the definite article (*sans la foi*). Is there a rule here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are MANY examples of prepositional constructions lacking articles in French: *à cheval*, *sous clef*, *contre nature* (which are usually used as some sort of adverbials). “*sans doute*” falls into that category, note that qualifying them (as Grevisse notes) usually causes the article to reappear: *sans le moindre doute*, *sans un seul doute* (*aucun* being a determiner itself and thus preventing articles, *sans aucun doute* is an obvious exception).

Grevisse, oddly enough, seems not to take notice that the *partitive* form of the indefinite article (*de, du, des*) seems to be disallowed after *sans* (this covers the “*sans alcool*” case). I think that means *de* is not allowed to follow other prepositions (at §1039 1<sup>o</sup> c, he discusses sequences of prepositions: when *de* is present, it always comes first).